# Replace words in a text file with different words (python)

Tags: python, replace

I am trying to replace the words in a textfile with English words (kind of like a translator). However, I get the error **builtins.NameError: name 'contents' is not defined**. Incase you need to know, the textfile is a list of strings (in Chinese) separated by commas (to which I need to replace by English strings).

```
def translate():
    contents = ""
    deleteWords = ["hop", "job"]
    replaceWords = {"T波改变": "T-wave", "窦性心律不齐":"sinus arrhythmia"}

    with open("sample.txt") as diagnosis:
        contents = diagnosis.read()
    for key, value in replaceWords.iteritems():
        contents = contents.replace(key, value)
    return contents
print(contents)
```

Comment: the `NameError` is because you're referencing a variable created within the scope of your function, but it does not exist outside of that function. Try `print(translate())`

Answer (score 2):

You declare `contents` inside your function, so it is scoped to this function and can not be accessed outside of the function.

Try: `print(translate())` instead of `print(contents)`

Comment: I got the error:

for key, value in replaceWords.iteritems():
builtins.AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: Try 'items' instead of 'iteritems'. 'iteritems' was used in an older version of Python.

Answer (score 1):

The `contents` is a private variable that is only available inside of the function and is up for recycling as soon as the function is done. You need to call the function and save its value.

```
def translate():
    contents = ""
    #deleteWords = ["hop", "job"]  # This variable is unused so commented out. Delete this line
    replaceWords = {"T波改变": "T-wave", "窦性心律不齐":"sinus arrhythmia"}

    with open("sample.txt") as diagnosis:
        contents = diagnosis.read()
    for key, value in replaceWords.iteritems():
        contents = contents.replace(key, value)
    return contents

# Here contents is a different variable with the same value
contents = translate()  # <== Added this line to make it work
print(contents)
```

Comment: `contents = translate()` is the call added to the code. That is the change required